# How to detect iphone supports live photo or not

Tags: ios, phlivephoto

i am doing one application.In that i want to implement the live photo feature.So before doing that first i want to check that device supports the live photo feature or not.So please guide me how to detect my device supports live photos or not.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32864449/api-to-capture-live-photos-in-ios9

Comment: The iPhone 6s and newer support live photo. Just to detect which iPhone model you can know whether it supports live or not. For detecting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26028918/ios-how-to-determine-the-current-iphone-device-model-in-swift

Comment: This method, of detecting iPhone model, seems fragile to me. That is, you have to update it with new hardware.